# How to return success in below code for using asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await

hello i write this code in asp.net core. for api request. so i will write return keyword in this code. what should i do to access a return keyword in below code?

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("UserDelete")]
        public async Task UserDelete(string Id)
        {
            try
            {
              await _ICcontext.UserRegistrationDelete(Id);
            }
            catch(Exception Ex)
            {
                throw Ex;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply return with method `OK()` or `Json()` with the object you want to serialize.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UserDelete")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserDelete(string Id)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(await _ICcontext.UserRegistrationDelete(Id));
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {
            LogException(Ex);
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @KeyurKakadiya It depends on what you want to return. You need to be clear that are you trying to return a JSON? Or a view? Or maybe some redirects? If you are not clear, try just return Ok(); will generate an empty view();

Comment: when My JSON file has data it would be return that data other wise return empty JSON file in API